# Nuget server setup

Tags: nuget, nuget-server

I am trying to setup a private nuget server in my company, and there will be different group of people using it.

I noticed that there is an entry in web.config to set a shared API key for publishing an package.

Is there a way of setting up different api keys for every user? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way of creating API keys is to ask each user to register themselves via the web front-end.

The instructions are basically those here: http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/12/uploading-packages-to-the-nuget-gallery.aspx although of course the users will use an internal URL, not http://nuget.org/

Less work for you, and users get an introduction to NuGet Gallery!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have API keys for each user like the public NuGet gallery does, you'll need to run your own internal [NuGet gallery](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/contribute/setting-up-a-local-gallery).  The instructions in NuGet's documentation has a walkthrough of getting this set up.  It uses Orchard for the gallery.

Answer (score -1):

Just FYI, you could also save yourself the trouble and get you a private MyGet feed using one of the 3 subscription based plans (or the cheap [Enterprise Plan](http://www.myget.org/plans) might sound useful to you). [MyGet](http://www.myget.org) by default gives every user his own personal API key. There's also a free public plan.

[image: MyGet user-specific API key]